# MySQL query select performance and two date range in one select

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table to store number of humans in stores like this:

```
id primary int 
id_store int 
date date 
time_begin time 
time_end time 
girl int 
boy int 
man int 
deleted int 
KEY id_store
KEY date 
KEY time_begin
```

Data:

```
id  store  date        time_begin  time_end   girl  boy  man  deleted
1   10     2015-01-01  09:00:00    09:05:00   5     7    8    0 
2   10     2015-01-01  09:05:00    09:10:00   3     2    1    0 
3   10     2015-01-01  09:10:00    09:15:00   5     4    7    0  
4   10     2015-01-01  09:15:00    09:20:00   5     3    8    0 
5   20     2015-01-01  09:00:00    09:05:00   7     8    2    0 
6   20     2015-01-01  09:00:00    09:05:00   5     7    8    0 
7   20     2015-01-01  09:05:00    09:10:00   3     2    1    0 
8   20     2015-01-01  09:10:00    09:15:00   5     4    7    0 
9   20     2015-01-01  09:15:00    09:20:00   5     3    8    0
```

Can have 1000 stores and every 5 minutes will have 1 record to save girl/boy/man for each store. This table can contain over 1bil of records.

I want to summarize all demography in date/time range of some stores, here is my query:

```
SELECT id_store, SUM(girl) girl ,SUM(boy) boy,SUM(man) man 
FROM report_demography 
WHERE 
date between "2015-08-01" and "2015-08-31" 
and time_begin >= "09:00:00" AND time_begin < "22:00:00" 
AND deleted = 0 AND FIND_IN_SET(id_store,'10,20,30,40,50')
GROUP BY id_store
```

It take 2.51 minutes to run this query (total rows in this table is 900K). Is there anyway to improve this query?

And one more thing: I want to combine the demography results of last month in this query, I use union all but seemed it's not a best solution.

This is EXPLAIN SELECT: [image](id_station is same with id_store)

Best regards

Comment: What does `explain select ...` says for this query add them into the question.

Comment: Change FIND_IN_SET(id_store,'10,20,30,40,50') with id_store in (10,20,30,40,50) and report back if you still have the issue. You can also index deleted.

Comment: @AdrianBR: thanks you. It's worked great, now take only 8-10s. But it still not enough for me If I UNION with the same query to get last month data. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you can potentially get another small boost by replacing "between" with the corresponding <> equations. The same for indexing 'deleted' since it will give it a chance to be used in the filtering. You mai also get a small performance boost by creating a composite index on (deleted, date, time).

Further than this there is not much you can do to optimise besides allocation more resources to your server. Also make sure when you union that you do not use any subqueries. If you are using subqueries, and cannot rewrite, you can consider using temporary tables.

Comment: @AdrianBR: I posted my answer below, thank you and I still need your help in another case.

Comment: @ Abhik: Do you have any help with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 example I had tried:

> CREATE TABLE `report_demography` ( 
>    `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `id_station` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    `datee`
>   date NOT NULL,
>    `girl` int(11) NOT NULL,
>    `boy` int(11) NOT
>   NULL,  
>    `man` int(11) NOT NULL, 
>    `deleted` int(11) NOT
>   NULL DEFAULT '0', 
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>    KEY `id_station`
>   (`id_station`),
>    KEY `datee` (`datee`),
>    KEY `time_begin`
>   (`time_begin`),
>    KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
>    KEY
>   `main_condition` (`deleted`,`id_station`,`datee`,`time_begin`) 
>  )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=969628 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

I tried two cases: 
**- use full condition:**

> SELECT id_station, SUM(girl) girl ,SUM(boy) boy,SUM(man) man
>  FROM
>   report_demography
>  WHERE datee BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND
>   "2015-07-01"
>  AND time_begin >= "09:00:00" AND time_begin <
>   "22:00:00"
>  AND deleted = 0
>  AND id_station IN
>   (668,782,672,670,139,878,671,785,736,737,740,787,138,141,789,669,835,783,780,781,788,784,809,786)
>   GROUP BY id_station

it's about 0.7 seconds => best case
explain: 
[image]

**- not use id_station(select all stores):**

> SELECT id_station, SUM(girl) girl ,SUM(boy) boy,SUM(man) man 
>  FROM
>   report_demography1 
>  WHERE datee BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND
>   "2015-07-01" 
>  AND time_begin >= "09:00:00" AND time_begin <
>   "22:00:00" 
>  AND deleted = 0 
>  GROUP BY id_station

it's about 03:17:99 seconds => worse case 
explain select: 
[image]

Seemed case 2 Using where in Extra column instead of Index, how do I use right index in this case?

Comment: First, the result of explain extended might be more useful Using where does not mean it's not using indices. Perhaps explain extended can clarify.
In case 2 you can use index hints. Also try replacing the between with </> condition, since the between can sometimes negatively impact.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: You can also benefit from changing deleted datatype to something smaller such as tinyint or ideally ENUM(1 byte) if your values are boolean

Answer (score 0):

Although you appear to have one partial answer by using Store IN (…), the reason you are not getting a more efficient result is because your indexes are not optimized.  Sometimes people think an index should be on several INDIVIDUAL columns which is incorrect.  You want to have an index that best matches the query WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER conditions.

In your case, you want based on 4 parts.  First, you WHERE clause, then the group by.  To help, start with the fields in your WHERE clause.  So create a SINGLE index on

```
( id_store, deleted, date, time_begin )
```

to clarify the where..

```
WHERE
       id_store IN ( 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 )
   AND deleted = 0
   AND date >= '2015-08-01'
   AND date <= '2015-08-31'
   AND time_begin >= '09:00:00'
   AND time_begin < '22:00:00'
group by
   id_store
```

Now, to get comparison of prior month too, you could create your own cross-tab something like

```
select
      rd.id_store,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 7 then girl else 0 end ) as GirlJuly,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 8 then girl else 0 end ) as GirlAug,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 7 then boy else 0 end ) as BoyJuly,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 8 then boy else 0 end ) as BoyAug,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 7 then man else 0 end ) as ManJuly,
      sum( case when month( rd.Date ) = 8 then man else 0 end ) as ManAug      
   from
      report_demography rd
   WHERE
          rd.id_store IN ( 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 )
      AND rd.deleted = 0
      -- I expanded the date to TWO months... 7/1 to 8/31
      AND rd.date >= '2015-07-01'
      AND rd.date <= '2015-08-31'
      AND rd.time_begin >= '09:00:00'
      AND rd.time_begin < '22:00:00'
   group by
      rd.id_store
```

Now, this could be written with more generic column name results like LastMonth, PriorMonth (for girl, boy, man respectively), and also an easier way to handle dates too.

Last question, why do you have time restrictions.  If these are counts from store activity reporting, and someone reports at ex: 8:27, why NOT include it... it would still be a total for the day... not critical, just inquiring.